# Entity Framework Joining multiple tables and display multiple data sets

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

this is my code to fetch data from multiple table and return it as json. However it only allow one to one relationship.

Problem: DoctorNote have multiple result sets, i am having problem fetching the data. Error"Sequence contains more than one element". Any suggestion on how i can fetch the many relationship results?

```
    var person = (from p in _context.Patients
                      join e in _context.PatientAllocations
                      on p.patientID equals e.patientID
                      join d in _context.DoctorNotes
                      on p.patientID equals d.patientID
                      where p.patientID == patientID
                      select new
                      {
                              patient_patientID = p.patientID,
                              patient_isDeleted = p.isDeleted,
                              patient_isApproved = p.isApproved,
                              patient_updateBit = p.updateBit,
                              patientallocation_caregiverID = e.caregiverID,
                              patientallocation_doctorID = e.doctorID,
                              DoctorNote_doctorNoteID = d.doctorNoteID,
                              DoctorNote_note = d.note,
                              DoctorNote_createDateTime = d.createDateTime,
                              DoctorNote_patientID = d.patientID,
                              DoctorNote_isApproved = d.isApproved,
                              DoctorNote_isDeleted = d.isDeleted,
                      }).ToList().SingleOrDefault();
        return Ok(person);
```

Comment: If you need multiple results, why are you using FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: @MBakardzhiev Because if i dont use FirstOrDefault(), it will give me an error. "he 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

Comment: The inner exception could give you more details about the error. What does it say?

By the way, make sure you have a model class where you load the data from the query, like Person.

Comment: I rolled back your revisions because you changed the code to something that doesn't throw the exception, rendering the question useless.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is thrown by `SingleOrDefault` method, so based on that fact it seems your query returns more than one element.

To get collection of `DoctorNotes`, just remove `SingleOrDefault` method from your query

Comment: I removed SingleOrDefault/FirstOrDefault. It gives me an error "he 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'."

Comment: You are using XML serializer, so it seems it can't serialize your collection of anonymous objects. In order to circumvent the issue, you can make class which will represent that object, and decorate its properties according to your XML serializer needs. Also if you don't use XML serializer, and you are using Json serializer, Content Type header of request should be 'application/json' instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SingleOrDefault()` which assume that your query will return at most  one record. You may try `FirstOrDefault()` it assume query can return any number of record and you want first.
You may see [this](https://gist.github.com/symphonicsky/1557219) to understand difference between the two

```
                | 0 values    | 1 value     | > 1 value
FirstOrDefault  | Default     | First value | First value
SingleOrDefault | Default     | First value | Exception
```

Comment: If i change to FirstOrDefault(), it is fetching only 1 result. I need to display multiple result for DoctorNotes.

Comment: what happen f you FirstOrDefault(). what is return type of function in which query is present

Comment: I uploaded an example and edited the question. Pelase take a look thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The query still returns 3 DocterNotes. 
The FirstOrDefault is on the total query, not on the DocterNotes.

Can you add a where clause? 
For example, this should work:

```
where p.patientID == patientID
and DoctorNote_doctorNoteID == 3
```